# String or integer to date(year fromat) pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am able to convert column into date format in my pandas dataframe using the datetime function. the only problem I seem to have is the format now that comes with my original year. How do I convert my year column without having to add the month, time etc... the Below is what I wish to obtain

```
 df['year']=2015 ----> transformed = df['year']=2015
```

No month, day or time added.

Comment: Can you show how you parsed the datetime? Looks like something is wrong at that part.

Comment: Year alone cannot be a datetime object. You need all three to make at least a date object. Individually they are just integeres. Or maybe I don't get your question (most probable)

Comment: I have not. This is what I wish to have...but I am using daTETIME  AND it changes the whole format of data. I just want year

Comment: If you only want a year, you must use an int or a pd.TimeDelta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question.

If you want to parse a column as datetime, simply use

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')`,

where `format` must be adapted to your case. This data will be in `datetime64` format. After the parsing, you can extract year, month and day with the following:

`df['year'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)`

Values in `df['year']` will **not** be `datetime64`, it will be `int64`, so I am confused to what conversion you are talking about.

Comment: when I am parsing my 'Year' column I have something 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002015. All I need is the year at the end. But pandas seems to be giving  me imaginary year.

Comment: Good I got it thanks... the format had to  a string before it can be parsed